# Ingest "t" and "f" as boolean to Cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, boolean, spark-cassandra-connector

I use pyspark to load a csv as dataframe, then save it to Cassandra. One of the columns is defined as boolean in Cassandra's schema, but my actual data in csv are string `t` or `f`. Is there any chance I can make Cassandra recognize `t` and `f` as boolean? Otherwise I have to add a data transformation step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark Cassandra Connector [uses `String.toBoolean` call](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/driver/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/types/TypeConverter.scala#L106) to convert strings to boolean values. But it accepts only `true` and `false`, and throws an exception if it's used with other strings.  So you'll need to write small data transformation code, like this:

```
scala> val df = Seq((1, "t"), (2, "f"), (3, "t")).toDF("id", "b")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, b: string]

scala> val df2 = df.withColumn("b", $"b" === "t")
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, b: boolean]

scala> df2.show()
+---+-----+
| id|    b|
+---+-----+
|  1| true|
|  2|false|
|  3| true|
+---+-----+
```